# Как правильно обработать строку?

Tags: c#, строки

Есть строка, которая может иметь следующий вид, числа в конце строки каждый раз разные:

```
var str = "{Count}-1"
var str = "{Count}+5"
var str = "{Count}/3"
var str = "{Count}*2"
```

Как мне обработать эту строку, что бы в строке осталось просто var `str = "{Count}"`, в отдельной переменной было бы арифметическое действие, например: `var arifm = "+"` и в третьей переменной было бы число, например: `var count = 10`. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: а) Написать регулярку б) написать небольшой конечный автомат.

Comment: `String.Substring` ? но регулярную точно правильнее.

Comment: Вам небось нужен парсер арифметических выражений?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение с помощью регулярки:

```
var pattern = @"(?'param'\{\w+\})(?'arifm'.)(?'count'\d+)";
var input = @"{Count}-1";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var param = match.Groups["param"].Value;
var arifm = match.Groups["arifm"].Value;
var count = match.Groups["count"].Value;
```

Регулярка простая, для удобства использования я добавил именованные группы.

```
\{\w+\} — захватывает фигурные скобки и последовательность (1 и более)
              букв/цифр/подчеркивания между ними
.       — захватывает один любой символ
\d+     — захватывает последовательность (1 и более) цифр
(?'name'pattern) — создает именованную группу, соответствующую шаблону pattern,
                       значение которой потом можно будет извлечь по имени name
```

Можно укоротить регулярку до такой: `(\{\w+\})(.)(\d+)`, но извлекать группы придется по индексам (отсчет с 1, т. к. нулевая группа — весь шаблон полностью):

```
var param = match.Groups[1].Value;
var arifm = match.Groups[2].Value;
var count = match.Groups[3].Value;
```